# replace first occurrence from right and left side of string

Tags: php

I tried to replace first occurance of a json string `{` from right side, and left side `}` .

```
$json_data = preg_replace( '/\{/' , '', $json_data ,1 );
$json_data = rtrim( $json_data ,'}' ); // here is issue
```

but string like this `{"chart":"c12","series":{"name":"Test","data":[]}}` replaced into

```
"chart":"c12","series":{"name":"Test","data":[]
```

The rtrim replaced '}}' . how to replace the first occurance of `}` from the right side of string ?

Comment: is there any reason why you don't use `json_decode()` on your string ?

Comment: `substr($string, 1, -1);` ?

Comment: @Twisted1919 I have to add a function to it , `$json_data .= ', onClick : function(){ /*..here some code..*/ }'; $json_data = '{'. $json_data .'}';`

Comment: json_decode() it then you will have an object. Based on that, add the onclick or any other element as simple as `$decodedJson->onclick = 'function()...';` then encode it back with `json_encode()`. DO NOT write your own json parser.

Comment: On encoding, it will add quotes around `function...`

Comment: see json_encode flags: http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: @OneTrickPony thanks ur comment .. ur code helps me `$json_data = substr( substr($json_data, 1 ) , 0 , -1 );` works perfect . could u add as answer .. so I can mark as correct answer

Comment: @OneTrickPony how could I make js object like ` `{"chart":"c12","series":{"name":"Test","data":[]}, onClick:function(){ alert("hi")}}` from server side .. I will insert this in `<script>` . I think my above method is not fine ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_data = preg_replace('/^\s*\{\s*(.+)\s*\}\s*$/', '$1', $json_data);
```

However, it's difficult to imagine the situation when it's necessary.

Comment: thanks for ur answer . how could I make js object like ` `{"chart":"c12","series":{"name":"Test","data":[]}, onClick:function(){ alert("hi")}}` from server side ? . the json assign to javascript variable insert this in `<script>`

Comment: You're able to `eval` this JSON-string in JS to get JS-object with proper function definition. `var obj = eval('<?php echo $json_data; ?>')` or even `var obj = <?php echo $json_data ?>` However this approach may have some security issues if you are not sure about source of JSON.

Comment: yes .. there is some security issues on cient side eval .. I would like to do this from server side .

Comment: Do you want to execute JS-function on server side?? I think this is not possible in PHP.

Comment: It seems that your problem is more complicated. Create new question with more explanations about what you have and what you want to get. Maybe the community will help you with an advise how to get it working.